# solve this differential equation with using Laplace transforms .

Tags: differential

$$(t+2)x''+(t+1)x'-x=0, \qquad x(0)=0, \qquad x'(0)=2$$
and this $$ tx''-tx+4x=2e^t ::  x(0)=sinh 1 ; $$

with using Derived from Laplace we get :
$$
\begin{split}
L(ty'') &= −s2Y'(s)−2sY(s)+y(0) \\
L(ty')  &= -sY'(s)−Y(s)\\
L(ty)   &= −Y'(s)\\
L(y')   &= sY(s)−y(0)
\end{split}
$$

and when we put them in equation we get :

$$L[x](2s^2-s-2)-L'[x](s+s^2)=4s+4$$

how to solve the rest ?

how to solve this equation with laplace transform;

$$ tx''-tx+4x=2e^t ::  x(0)=sinh 1 ; $$

Comment: Please use MathJax for math typesetting. You can encase your math in `$` a la `$mx+b$` to get $mx+b$ or with `$$` a la `$$mx+b$$` to get $$mx+b.$$ Also avoid using `"` and `′` in math text. It does not render super well. For derivatives, simply use `'` --- a single quote (not a smart quote either!).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach for the sake of curiosity.

According to the substitution $u = x' + x$, we reduce the proposed ODE as follows:

\begin{align*}
(t+2)x'' + (t+1)x' - x = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (t+2)(x' + x)' - (x' + x) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (t+2)u' - u = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: this way is smart but is there any direct way to solve this from what i got ?@user0102

Comment: As far as I know, the Laplace transform is used to solve linear differential equations with constant coefficients, which is not the case. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: yeah but this question was in my exam and i think nobody solved it so i had to seek for answer , i want to make sure that is there any way to solve this directly or not . thanks for your help. @user0102